# Installing Google Maps giving error "Application requires newer SDK version"

Tags: google-play-store, updates, google-maps

I have a galaxy S 3(d2att,US variant). Today I got an update for Google Maps.
But when I try to update it after downloading play store gives error as "**Application requires newer SDK version**".
I'm running on 4.2.2 Jellybean. Phone is rooted and using CynogenMod 10.1.2.

How can I update it? or Why it shows so?

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps needs the correct version of gapps to work. Download the [gapps](http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip) and install it from recovery

Comment: From what I know, maps is not included

Comment: But gapps has other google apps, play store etc built in, maps needs the version of gapps to match what is on your phone to work. It's a conflict. Give it a go and see how it works out!

Comment: I have the latest Gapps installed..but I can't update. Always giving this error.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the data of the playstore app? If that doesnt work, try wiping cache and dalvik cache from the recovery. If it's still not working, download the apk from [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/09/12/whats-really-newapk-teardown-google-maps-update-v7-2-rolling-out-google-now-style-navigation-card-hotel-rates-htc-contacts-bug-fix-and-more-apk-download/#download)